# GET Method in ASP.Net MVC is not getting called on button click from Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Im new to ASP.Net MVC. I have a button and click of the button I need to return a JSON object. The button click should make a ajax call to call the get method. My get method is not at all getting called, rather my index method is getting called.

Controller :

```
 public ActionResult PageLoad()
    {
        return View("PackBOMQuotePreferred");
    }

     [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult RetreivePackData()
    {

        IEnumerable<MPMPackInfo> oListOfPacks = null;
        try
        {
           oListOfPacks = _service.GetListOfPacks();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _errorLog.Error(ex);
        }
        return Json(oListOfPacks, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

.cshtml

```
 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "PackBOMQuotePreferred";
}

<h2>PackBOMQuotePreferred</h2>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <div id="errorMsgBoard" class="error">
 </div>
<div>
    <input type="button" class ="btn btn-primary start"  id ="btnRetreivePackData" value="Retreive Pack Data" />
    <input type="button" class ="btn btn-primary start" id ="btnRetreiveBOMData" value="Retrieve BOM Data" />
    <input type="button" class ="btn btn-primary start" id ="btnRetreiveQUoteData" value="Retrieve Quote Data" />
    <input type="button" class ="btn btn-primary start" id ="btnRetreivePreferredData" value="Retrieve Preferred Data" />
</div>




<script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">
    $("#btnRetreivePackData").on("click", function ()
    {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            Url: 'PackBOMQuotePreferred/RetreivePackData',
            datType:'json',
            cache: false,
            data: {},
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            Success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert(response);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error - ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

If i Look at fiddler, it shows GET /PackBOMQuotePreferred/PageLoad?_=1412451506195 HTTP/1.1 , means by RetreivePackData is not getting called. I dont see any error in chrome console.

Not sure what am I doing wrong.

Comment: There are some properties misspelled you pass to the $.ajax function in your .cshtml file. Try changing "Url" to "url", "Success" to "success" and "datType" to "dataType"

Answer (score 0):

Edit your URL. it should be

```
Url: '/PackBOMQuotePreferred/RetreivePackData/',
```

and you also misspelled `datatype` to `dattype`